# How to setup a connection timeout depending of the user login in MySQL

Tags: mysql, timeout

I have currently more than 100 connections in Sleep state.

Some connection must stay in Sleep state (and don't close) because it's permanent connection but some others (with a different user name) are from some php script and I want them to timeout very fast.

Is it possible to setup a wait_timeout per user? and if yes, How?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's no per-user timeout configuration, but you can set the `wait_timeout` value dynamically.  That is, after you make a connection as a given user, you can issue a statement to change the timeout value to what you want it to be for that user's session.

Try the following experiment in the mysql command-line client:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
```

...shows 28800 (i.e. 8 hours), which is the default `wait_timout`.

```
mysql> SET SESSION wait_timeout = 60;
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
```

...shows 60.

Then you can quit the session, reconnect, and again the default `wait_timeout` is 28800.  So it's limited to the scope of the current session.

You can also open a second window and start a separate mysql client session, to prove that changing the `wait_timeout` in one session does not affect other concurrent sessions.

Answer (score 6):

You should set the following variables in your `my.conf`:

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=180
wait_timeout=180
```

`wait_timeout` is a timeout for **automated connections** (*in my opinion more than 30 on a web server is too much*).
`interactive_timeout` is a **console interaction timeout** for idle session.

Comment: Many (most?) web servers use connection pooling.  In this case, 180 is probably too low.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:  MySQL supports two different timeout variables, `wait_timeout` for non-interactive clients, and `interactive_timeout` for interactive clients.

The difference between interactive and non-interactive clients seems to be simply whether you specified the `CLIENT_INTERACTIVE` option when connecting.

I don't know if this helps you, because you need to somehow make `mysql_real_connect()` pass that option in its `client_flag` parameter.  I'm not sure what language or interface you're using, so I don't know if it permits you to specify this connection flag.

Anyway if you can pass that client flag, and you only need two different types of users, then you could configure `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` differently in the MySQL server config, and then use the one with the shorter value when you want a given session to time out promptly.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), you can use **sessionVariables** in the client's JDBC URL like so: `jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/schema?sessionVariables=wait_timeout=600`

Other connectors for other languages will probably allow the same.

Answer (score 2):

init_connect will be executed whenever a user logs in, so we can write small case statement and set the value based on user. Please note that the init_connect won't be executed for super user.

`mysql> SET GLOBAL init_connect="SET @@wait_timeout = CASE WHEN CURRENT_USER() LIKE 'app1@%' THEN '30' ELSE @@wait_timeout END";`

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `mysql.user` table and it doesn't look like there is a setting there for it:

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                  | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                  | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password              | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |       |
| Select_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| File_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv   | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_user_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type              | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher            | blob                              | NO   |     |         |       |
| x509_issuer           | blob                              | NO   |     |         |       |
| x509_subject          | blob                              | NO   |     |         |       |
| max_questions         | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates           | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections       | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_user_connections  | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
37 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Depending on whether you're using MySQLi or PDO, your PHP MySQL connections should either hang up when the request does, or be shared in a pool for the Apache process.

For example, with PDO, to turn off persistent connections (I think this is the default), connect to your DB with:

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, Array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));

If you want your scripts to use persistent connections, but you have too many connections open to your database in sleep mode, you should think about configuring your Apache's `MaxServers`, `MaxSpareServers`, `MinSpareServers` and `StartServers` so that not so many hang around when they aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-kill.html

It is possible to kill connections per user with pt-kill. You can schedule this or set up a background job to handle this.