# how to change timeout for mysql persistent connections

Tags: mysql, persistent-connection

Where is defined timeout of persistent connections? Is it possible to change it?

Comment: Related: [How to setup a connection timeout depending of the user login in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/243644/1288)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) parameter for my.ini

Comment: i added wait_timeout=120 in my.cnf but still have same value as before (checked with select @@wait_timeout;)

Comment: Also check interactive_timeout.

Comment: @user198003: did you restart mysql after changing the value? There may be multiple my.ini's on your system - make sure you're changing the right one.

Comment: sure i restarted it. but it was necessary to add interactive_timeout option, as mark rose mention.