# MySQL server has gone away - ErrorException

Tags: php, mysql, exception

I started getting this error when trying to query the database on a connection that had timed out.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'mysql_query(): MySQL server has gone away'
```

So I did a bunch of research and 99% of the users on the forum say you can use the **mysql_ping** command to check for a connection, so I put this in place:

```
if(!mysql_ping($this->sDBLink))
    Connect(true);
```

Now I get the same error, just in reference to the **mysql_ping** function instead of the **mysql_query** function:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'mysql_ping(): MySQL server has gone away'
```

**How do I reliably check that a connection still exists?**  mysql_ping throws an exception.

Comment: _'MySQL server has gone away'_ is an hilarious exception message - a Microsoft defector, perhaps?

Comment: From what I understand, it means the connection has timed out.  I create my connection early on in the program.  When I try use the same connection later on it gives this error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a PDO or mysqli object instead? They've deprecated this extension and I've never seen this error using either of the other two.

Comment: You need to trap an error on the connection, ping only works if its established a connection to the server.  If you trap the error on the connection then you can abort application loading and flag a nice connection error instead.

Comment: Is your global setting mysql.reconnect enabled? Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php#ini.mysqli.reconnect

Comment: If you know the operation is going to take a while, extend the time out on connection.

Comment: I would extend the connection time it wasn't completely variable. In a nutshell the program uploads a collection of images, videos, music along with an xml file.  Once it has uploaded all that it updates the database. Now, the video can be 50mb it can be 5gb. There is no limit as this is a B2B solution.

Comment: Does it not have a maximum expectation that you can set the timeout above?

Comment: I guess it will never run for longer than 12 hours.  I could extend it till then.  I am going to post my solution that I found just below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I know this is ugly and makes me sick it, but it will work until we can get enough income to warrant an upgrade.

All I did was close the connection then recreate it as I know the connection will have timed out almost 95% of the time.

```
if($this->sDBLink){
    mysql_close($this->sDBLink);
}

if($bPersistant){
    $this->sDBLink = mysql_pconnect($this->sHostname, $this->sUsername, $this->sPassword);
} else {
    $this->sDBLink = mysql_connect($this->sHostname, $this->sUsername, $this->sPassword);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why does a connection time out? Because it has been unused for a period of time longer than a particular threshold.  This kind of thing is necessary for all kinds of network applications to make them resilient.  What if a user abruptly switches off a client machine while it is connected to a MySQL server? The server needs to be able to drop the client connection after a while.

This kind of thing is inherent in network programming. It's a feature, not a bug.

What can you do about this?

You can switch to a more modern mysql connection management library that handles this stuff.

Especially if your client software gets used infrequently, you can reorganize your software to connect to MySQL, use the connection, and disconnect. That way you won't need a persistent connection.  But that's impractical if your client server gets used a lot; there's a lot of overhead to establishing a connection.

You can change the timeout value.  See here. [how to change timeout for mysql persistent connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948004/how-to-change-timeout-for-mysql-persistent-connections)

You can use the connection regularly.  mysql_ping uses the connection without actually doing any server work. So would a query that said something like `SELECT 1`.  If you ping the connection every minute or so, then a two minute timeout won't cause your MySQL server to conclude that your client has gone away and disconnect it.

You can handle the ErrorException you're getting correctly, by trying to re-establish the connection instead of just blowing out your program with an error message. Use PHP code something like this:

```
try {
    some operation on the mysql connection.
}
catch (ErrorException $ex) {
    disconnect mysql
    connect mysql
}
```

Comment: I agree completely. The project is one I have inherited. I am making some small changes to a complex solution. I don't feel comfortable changing the library until I know more about how it can affect code already using this class.

Comment: This answer contains an important detail: After the mySQL server "has gone away", PHP still considers this your database connection, even if it's broken, and as such will return the same old broken link on a re-connect unless you close the connection first. (Or explicitly request a new one, which would probably leak memory over time, as the old ones won't get cleaned up.) Thanks for the hint! :-)