# mysqli_multi_query information required

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using `mysqli_multi_query` to `update` table.
can someone tell me max how many records I can update in single query
e.g I've `25K (25000) records` and either these will be `update` by a `single statement` or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really running an `UPDATE` query, there's no theoretical limit on rows you can update. The real issues are timeouts amd memory limits.

Comment: I try to update but it gave an error `fatal error: server gone away`

Comment: That's a problem with your MySQL server settings. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4948039/2057919) to fix it. If you can't change your my.ini file, you may need to break the query into chunks through trial and error to figure out what works for your server.