# User-specific mysql timeout

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to set a `SELECT` timeout for a **specific** mysql user? The following question address this for any user on a database -- [How to set a maximum execution time for a mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query) -- but I want to set it only for a specific mysql user, the user given below.

```
Id  User    Host            db  Command Time    State                 Info
97  tvs0XXX ec2...com:47703 ax  Query   55      Creating sort index   SELECT...
```

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243644/how-to-setup-a-connection-timeout-depending-of-the-user-login-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define this using `max_execution_time` session variable (in milliseconds), something like:

```
SET SESSION max_execution_time=2000;
```

It should be done from a client for each session, so there is no way (currently) to assign this for a specific database user.